# How to print image with Bluebamboo device using objective c for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printing

am new in objective c development and working on a project, in which I am using External Accessory the device is Bluebamboo P25M printer and credit card swapper.

I have to print Image using this printer. Bluebamboo provided a SDK but in this SDK they are using a char type array of bitmap image. Now how can i made such array of my image so that it can print any image.

here is my code

```
 unsigned char buffer3[796]={
            0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31 ,  
            0x19, 0x20, 
             0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03
            ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xB0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xD8 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x13 ,0xEC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x04 
            ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x29 ,0xF4 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x64 ,0xF9 ,0x00
            ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xF9 ,0xC0 ,0x3D ,0xFF
            ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF2 ,0x73 ,0x80 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0
            ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0x7F ,0xFD ,0xE0 ,0x3D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x79 ,0x26 ,0xC0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
            ,0xFF ,0xFD ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x3C ,0x8F ,0x60
            ,0x0C ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0x80
            ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x9E ,0x8F ,0xB0 ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
            ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF8 ,0xFD ,0x80 ,0x33 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
            ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0x4F ,0x27 ,0xD8 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC 
            ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF9 ,0xFD ,0xFF ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x26 ,0x53 ,0xC8
            ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDD ,0xDD ,0xFF
            ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0xC9 ,0xF0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
            ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDF ,0x9D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
            ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC9 ,0xE4 ,0xE0 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x06 
            ,0xE7 ,0xFD ,0xCF ,0x9D ,0x80 ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xF0 ,0xF2 ,0x40
            ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xCF ,0x1D ,0x80
            ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0x79 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDF ,0xFC ,0xFF
            ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC7 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x49 ,0x3D ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9F ,0xFC ,0xFF ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
            ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC2 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1C ,0x9E ,0x00 
            ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x1F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xE1 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC0 ,0x1D ,0xFF
            ,0xE0 ,0xFF ,0xC1 ,0xFF ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x4C ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
            ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00   
            };


        //[self addLabel:@"buffer3 is selected"];
        [[session outputStream] write:(const uint8_t *)buffer3 maxLength:796];
```

Comment: @didn't you got sample code with this printer ,,look into that code you will get something inside it

Comment: @h.kishan i mentioned above code , this is what i get , and it also prints the image , but they didn't tell us how to convert image to this array

Comment: First convert your Image into NSData and send this data to ur printer as command

Answer (score 1):

Your image needs to first of all be in monochrome bitmap format.

Also, according to their document @ http://www.londatiga.net/downloads/P25_Development_Guide_V3.9(2012-12-31).pdf ,
you need to set some preliminary bytes to tell the printer that you're printing an image.

In the sample byte array, you see the following:

```
0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31 ,  
        0x19, 0x20,
```

0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88 indicate that the frame is starting, 0x44 is printing commands, 0x1B, 0x58, 0x31 are identifying that the printing type is a monochrome bmp.

0x19 is the pixels of the image width / 8. e.g. image width = 200. 200/8 = 25 px. 25px in hex is 0x19.
0x20 is the pixels of the image height. e.g. image height = 32 px. 32 in hex is 0x20.

http://bluebamboo.helpserve.com/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/132/5507

There's some sample code here that makes everything work.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]; // use name of your image

    CFMutableDataRef dataRef = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(img.CGImage)));

    UInt8 *pixelBuf = (UInt8*)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataRef);

    int length = CFDataGetLength(dataRef);

    NSString *hexStr = [NSString string];
    for(int i=0; i < length ; i++)
    {
        int pixInt = pixelBuf[i];
        hexStr = [hexStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%x",pixInt];

    }

    //create a complete string for receipt
    NSString *receiptStr = hexStr;
    int contentLength = [receiptStr length];

    //Print Receipt Data.
    Byte buff[contentLength+7];
    buff[0] = 0x55;
    buff[1] = 0x66;
    buff[2] = 0x77;
    buff[3] = 0x88;
    buff[4] = 0x44;  //Printing Command

    //Adding Print Contents
    for (int i=5; i < contentLength + 5; i++) {
        buff[i] = [receiptStr characterAtIndex:i-5];
    }


    buff[contentLength+5] = 0x0A;
    buff[contentLength+6] = 0x0A;




    [self setBtnDisabled];
    [sessionController writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)]];
```

Comment: //As i have also integrated blue bamboo ,,but didn't print image ,use above code and let me know whether it worked or not, as i didn't have ptinter with me right now

Comment: ok give some time and you also do some research , i will update code as soon as i get printer with me.

Answer (score 0):

First COnvert your Image into NSData and then print this data;

```
     UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"];
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
     [[session outputStream] writeData:imageData];
```

Comment: no this is not a format , format should be like above mentioned example

Comment: do you have any Image to print with bluebamboo??

Comment: Then put your image in my code.
Tha sample u have provided is creating image with HexCode and convert that code into NSData and then print.
I am also suggesting you the same Convert your Image into NSData and Print

Comment: let me check it again